# GradientBoostingClassifier and many columns

Tags: python, classification, gbm

I use GradientBoosting classifier to predict gender of users. The data have a lot of predictors and one of them is the country. For each country I have binary column. There are always only one column set to 1 for all country columns. But such desicion is very slow from computation point of view. Is there any way to represent country columns with only one column? I mean correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the binary variable with the actual country name then collapse all of these columns into one column. Use `LabelEncoder` on this column to create a proper integer variable and you should be all set.

Comment: But it is not correct for such data. Because country with id 1 is not less country with id 2. GBM dont know about it and try to find such rules. May find and it will be overfitting

Comment: I don't believe that it treats them as ordered, I made a mistake saying that. In the documentation for `LabelEncoder` they even use cities as an example so I would assume that this applies to countries as well. You can also check out `OneHotEncoder` from the same library if you don't believe `LabelEncoder` suits your needs.

Comment: I have never used `OneHotEncoder` but I believe you would enter something of a mixed column into it. For example, instead of one column being `country` and another being `color of hair` these two would be concatenated and you would have something like `[from Russia, has red hair]`. That being said I still believe `LabelEncoder` will suit your needs.